# What are some methods for finding global stability for this 3D system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, stability-in-odes

I am studying some biology system and arrives at this simplified dynamics:

\begin{align}
x_1' &= a_1 + a_2x_2 - a_1x_2 - a_4x_1 - a_5\frac{1+a_6x_3}{1+a_7x_3}x_1\\
x_2' &= a_5\frac{1+a_6x_3}{1+a_7x_3}x_1 - a_2x_2\\
x_3' &= a_8x_1 - a_9x_3
\end{align}
Where as the context and notation dictate: all coefficients $a_i$ are strictly positive. I also showed all $x_i$ to be strictly positive and bounded.

I have obtained locally-asymptotically stability for the unique positive fixed point. I also tried various lyapunov functions, but without much luck. I would really appreciate any idea to approach this problem -**please do not provide me with full solution**, perhaps a form of Lyapunov function, a direct method, etc that I should try.

Comment: what exactly are you hoping for? this looks like a complicated, non linear 3D ODE. there is no a priori reason to think there is an explicit solution, or a Lyapunov function. you could do numerical simulations toget an idea of the behaviour of the system. Also, since your system is linear if $a_5=0$, there is probably something interesting to say on the behaviour of your system if $a_5$ is very small

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki I have done numerical simulations and extensive bifurcation analysis which suggests global stability. In this case, it is unfortunate that $a_5$ is not negligible.

Comment: Are you sure that equations are correct? Shouldn't it be $+a_3 x_2$ or $+a_3 x_3$? As it's written now, some trajectories can escape the domain $x_1\geqslant 0, x_2\geqslant 0, x_3\geqslant 0$. Speaking about bifurcation analysis, can you write more about what you have done? Have you found all equilibria analytically and checked for Andronov-Hopf bifurcation, for example? Are there any saddle equilibria in this system?

Comment: @Evgeny I apologize. I corrected the equation. Please note that $x_1, x_2 < 1$. This system is a reduced form of a larger system. Please see: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330210/how-to-study-the-global-stability-for-this-3d-system/330313#330313